# Clarification in deduction of Ampere's original experiments

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, history

I am reading [Ampere's original work](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Amperes-Electrodynamics.pdf). Therein he describes an experiment called "equilibrium of opposite current experiment".

In this experiment, two immobile straight wires with current flowing in opposite directions are placed near each other. Then a mobile astatic coil is placed near them. It experiences zero torque.

Next he describes an experiment called "equilibrium of bent wire experiment".

In this experiment, an immobile bent wire and straight wire with current flowing in opposite directions are placed near each other. Then a mobile astatic coil is placed near them. It experiences zero torque.

Then he concludes that magnetic effects **of** bent wire in *"equilibrium of opposite current experiment"* is equivalent to magnetic effects **of** straight wire in *"equilibrium of bent wire experiment"*. This is fine.

But he also concludes (maybe without proof) that magnetic effects **on** bent wire in *"equilibrium of opposite current experiment"* is equivalent to magnetic effects **on** straight wire in *"equilibrium of bent wire experiment"*. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *[The electro]magnetic effects **on** bent wire in* "equilibrium of opposite current experiment" *is equivalent to [electro]magnetic effects **on** straight wire in* "equilibrium of bent wire experiment"*. Why is this so?*

Because Ampère was opposed to any violations of Newton's Third Law.

See §20.3 (pp. 261-262) of:

- André-Marie Ampère, [*Ampère’s Electrodynamics: Analysis of the Meaning and Evolution of Ampère’s Force between Current Elements, Together with a Complete Translation of His Masterpiece: Theory of Electrodynamic Phenomena, Uniquely Deduced from Experience*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5464), ed. André Koch Torres Assis, trans. J. P. M. C Chaib (Montreal: [Apeiron](http://redshift.vif.com/book_catalog.htm), 2015).